# I can't code it to copy a string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char converter(char input[]);
char getInformation (char input[]);

int main(){

  char c[99];
  int i;

  printf("Enter a Line:");
  scanf("%c", &c);

  while(i < 99){
    printf("%c\n", &c[i]);
    i++;
  }

}
```

Results for when I tried to run this

```
z:~/homework1: gcc -o hw1_1 hw1_1.c
z:~/homework1: hw1_1
Enter a Line:Test
Ø
Ù
Ú
Û
Ü
Ý
Þ
ß
à
á
â
ã
ä
å
æ
ç
è
é
ê
ë
ì
í
î
ï
ð
ñ
ò
ó
ô
õ
ö
÷
ø
ù
ú
û
ü
ý
þ
ÿ





































1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
:
z:~/homework1:
```

I'm trying to get it to read a text and print it out. Is there a way I can set the array to undefined number and how would I implement that into the while loop? Also can I have some guidance of how to check every character and change it's case (from lower case to upper case and the other way around). I think I can do this by checking the ASCII value of the character and flipping the numbers. For example if the character is a decimal value from 65-90, which are A-Z, I would add 32 to it to make it small. For character from 97-122, a-z, I would subtract 32. I don't need the answer but some hits would be nice. Thank you.

So far I've made these changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char converter(char input[]);
char getInformation (char input[]);

int main(){

  char c[30];
  int i;

  printf("Enter a Line: ");
  fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);


  i=0;
  while( i < sizeof(c)){
    printf("%s", c[i]);
    i++;
  }

}
```

This is what I get after trying to run this.

```
z:~/homework1: gcc -o hw1_1 hw1_1.c
z:~/homework1: hw1_1
Enter a Line: Test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
z:~/homework1: z:~/homework1:
```

Yes I got it! thanks a lot everyone!! Here is the code

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  char c[BUFSIZ];
  int i;

  printf("Enter a Line: ");
  fgets(c, BUFSIZ, stdin);

  i=0;
  for (i=0; i < sizeof(c); i++){

    if ((c[i] >= 65) && (c[i] <= 90) ){
      c[i] = c[i]+32;
    }else {
      if ((c[i] >=97) && (c[i] <= 122) ){
        c[i] = c[i]-32;
      }
    }
  }
```

and the results when I run it:

```
z:~/homework1: gcc -o hw1_1 hw1_1.c
z:~/homework1: hw1_1
Enter a Line: TeoijsTY;' ';lasd
tEOIJSty;' ';LASD

z:~/homework1:
```

This is the best feeling you can have, writing a working code! I wonder if I post this and my professors does a Google check of my code and think that I plagiarized? Anyways thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Initial value of `i` could be anything. Did you mean to initialize it?

Comment: Did you really think making all your text bold will help you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was easier to read. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read in a line via `scanf`, you use the format specifier for a `char`, you should use `%s` or, preferably, `%98s` to avoid overflow. On the other hand, when printing the characters one by one, you should pass the character itself as an argument to `printf` and not its address, so there it should be `printf("%c\n",c[i]);`.

To avoid printing out more characters than have been read in, you can first zero-fill the `char`-array, then scan with a width less than the array size to guarantee that you have a 0-terminated string in the array, and in the printing loop, check that `c[i] != 0`.

For the case conversions, the header `<ctype.h>` contains the necessary functions, that's better than to code them yourself. If you're not allowed to use them, your plan with the comparison with `'A' = 65` etc. works well for ASCII characters, but you may need to also consider characters in the range 128-255 (depends on your assignment).

Comment: Can you explain [quote] a little more? "To avoid printing out more characters than have been read in, you can first zero-fill the char-array, then scan with a width less than the array size to guarantee that you have a 0-terminated string in the array, and in the printing loop, check that c[i] != 0."

Comment: Actually, zero-filling isn't necessary because `scanf` automatically adds a 0-terminator with the `s` conversion specifier, but I use `scanf` so rarely I had to read the man page to be sure. Anyway, the point is that the entered line is followed by a `0` (`'\0'` if you prefer) character. You can use that value as a sentinel to know when you've reached the end, instead of `i < 99` you can check `c[i] != 0` or, to pacify paranoia, both conditions.

Comment: I made the changes(please see the edited question). I'm trying to use a way of not putting a limit on the number of characters I can use. But another error came up.

Comment: When you `printf("%s",c[i]);` the character `c[i]` is first promoted to `int` and then that `int` is passed to `printf`. Due to the format specifier `%s`, it is interpreted as a pointer to `char`. If pointers are larger than `int`, also some unrelated part of the stack is incorporated in the bits that are interpreted as the address where the string is. Anyway, the bits that are interpreted as the address probably point to a memory location not belonging to your process, thus causing the segfault. As paxdiablo said, to print single characters, you need `%c`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Check out the results at bottom of edited question.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` isn't really suited to reading a whole line. Use `fgets`.

```
char c[99];
fgets(c, 99, stdin);
```

Comment: Never, EVER use `gets`. `fgets` is the safe version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Check out the results at bottom of edited question.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c", &c);` will scan in a single character. to `c[0]`. It will not scan in a line.

Then your loop will print out 99 characters at a random location since you haven't initialised `i` to 0. Even if you had, you would print out all 99 characters, most of which are uninitialised.

That's why you're not getting a line, and why you're seeing rubbish in the output.

For line-based input, you need to look into `fgets`, which can safely input a line from the user (it has prevention of buffer overflow built in). Then, once you have the line, you can just use `printf ("%s\n", c)` or `puts(c)` to output it - no need to process it a character at a time.

If you're looking for a good way to use `fgets`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921). The full function is probably unsuitable for a homework assignment at this level but you can look at the code to see how it works. You *shouldn't* copy it verbatim unless you want to be accused of plagiarism but, by all means, use it to educate yourself.

Bottom line:

```
fgets (buff, size, handle);
```

will read characters from the file handle `handle` (use `stdin` for user input)  into memory at `buff`, limited in size by `size`.

The `getLine` function linked above will handle the edge cases like end-of-file detection, user entering a too-long line for the buffer and so on.

Function duplicated below for completeness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: This is a little to complitcated for me to understand. So far I've these changes (please see the edited question). I'm still stuck on getting it the right size without me having to put in a limit.

Comment: @user101699: a couple of problems with that. (1) you should use strlen rather than sizeof (the latter is the size of the array, the former the length of the string, which may be less). (2) you should use %c rather than %s (you're printing _characters,_ not strings). (3) You don't need to do _either_ of those :-) The whole loop can be replaced with `puts(c)`.

Comment: Thanks. I need the loop for the 2nd part of the assignment, which is checking every character than flipping the case. But I think your right, I can change the case then in the end use puts(c). Changing the %s to a %c did the trick. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Check out the results at bottom of edited question.